# Apache NIFI doesn't run on AWS EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-nifi

I have a ubuntu instance on AWS. I Installed Apache NiFi and run.

[image]

[image]

I open 8080 port on AWS security rule.

[image]

But when I use my pc with public IP, it doesn't work.
http://*.*.*.*:8080/nifi
Also, I checked this port for this IP still is close but I add an inbound rule and reboot.

[image]

This port is open on os.

[image]

Comment: Is the instance in a public subnet with a public IP address? Did you attach an Internet Gateway and is it referenced in the routing table?

Comment: Your final screenshot shows that your NiFi is only listening on 127.0.0.1:8080 which is localhost - you need to bind to your external interface. Look at the NOTE at the bottom of the Installation section https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#how-to-install-and-start-nifi  "For security purposes, when no security configuration is provided NiFi will now bind to 127.0.0.1 by default and the UI will only be accessible through this loopback interface."